# Cambio de icono de carrito en benzer template

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hola tengo woocommerce con la plantilla benzer y no he podido cambiar el icono del carrito.
Los codigos con los que he intentado cambiar a sido con el siguiente:

```
    .cart-contents .fa-shopping-cart:before {
    content: "\f291";
}
    <i class="fal fa-calculator fa-spin fa-lg" style="color: #337f10;"></i>
```

Otro codigo

```
    add_filter( 'generate_woocommerce_menu_cart_icon', 'tu_change_wc_menu_cart_icon' );
function tu_change_wc_menu_cart_icon() {
    return '<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
```

Y el tercero es

```
    add_filter( 'generate_woocommerce_menu_cart_icon', 'tu_change_wc_menu_cart_icon' );
function tu_change_wc_menu_cart_icon() {
    return '<i class="fal fa-calculator fa-spin fa-lg" style="color: #337f10;"></i>';
}
```

Estos codigos fueron sacados de otros foros. Tampoco he encontrado el nombre del icono de la cesta. Y lamentablemente no tengo mas informacion que dar .

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo el codigo del css con Firefox he podido encontrar la forma de cambiar el icono y darle un mayor tamaño al icono. Se añade en el css en el editor archivo de temas:

```
.fa-shopping-bag:before {
  content:"\f1ec";
  font-size:2.2em;
}
```

Asi se puede cambiar el icono del carrito de woocommerce, y ademas agrandarlo ( el icono) :) . Lo mas correcto seria poner este codigo bien en funcion.php o crear un subtema.
Este codigo funciona ya que lo pude comprobar.